# Conservation of left-handed quark current

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, chirality

I'm reading about the Operator Product Expansion in Gelis's A Stroll Through Quantum Fields section 7.4.2. As an example, he's using the product of currents

$$A_1^\mu = \overline{d}_L\gamma^\mu u_L$, $A_2^\mu = \overline{u}_L \gamma^\mu s_L.$$

He uses the fact that these currents are conserved at one loop order to say that the anomalous dimension is zero. I'm fine with that argument, but how do I see that these currents are in fact conserved? And which symmetry leads to this? In my limited experience with QCD, I've seen isospin current conservation which leads to $J^\mu_i = \overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu \frac{\tau_i}{2} \psi$ being conserved. But what allows us to say that the right and left handed components are individually conserved as well? Lastly, are there generators that Gelis has already taken care of? Or do they not show up in his case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very cornerstone of the Standard Model is the ***conservation of the currents*** to be coupled to gauge fields. Otherwise, the corresponding coupling terms would fail gauge invariance and the theory would not be renormalizable.  Take one generation for simplicity, first, so just *u,d* quarks.

The corresponding coupling term is $$g W^{-}_\mu \overline{d_L}~\gamma^\mu u_L,$$
and you *know* this current is conserved, since a left isorotation of the kinetic terms of the *left* fermions will produce it, but there won't be mass terms to provide a divergence for it. (The mass terms will arise from the Higgs Yukawa couplings, which as you recall, in SSB are features *always consistent with current conservation*: a symmetry is a symmetry, even if SSB! It is the *mode* of the realization of the symmetry that alters here.)

Now add a second generation doublet, with generation index *i*, so the left quark isocurrent is 
$$
g \vec W_\mu \cdot \overline{ \psi}^i~\gamma^\mu \vec \tau \psi_L^i, 
$$
whose relevant term due to Cabbibo mixing (first published by Gell-Mann and Lévy, but reportedly contributed by Feynman in 1960) is 
$$
g W^{-}_\mu (\cos\theta_c~  \overline{d_L}+ \sin \theta_c  \overline{s_L})~\gamma^\mu u_L, 
$$
and, of course, its hermitean conjugate.

Again, the current is conserved for every $\theta_c$, arbitrary, so *each* of its terms is separately conserved!  Moreover, the h.c. current coupling to $W^+$ is also conserved.

The cosine piece  you are looking at is your $A_1^\mu$, while the h.c. of the sine term is your $A_2^\mu$. I don't know why you choose these among lots of conserved pieces, since I have no access to your text, and, in any case, I strongly object to reading books together with the OP.

The right fermions are electroweak singlets and so, for ***massless*** quarks, as always, they also fall into an $SU(2)_R$ triplet, for 2 generations, and linear combinations with the left isocurrents above  give your the conserved vector isocurrent you mentioned (as well as 3 axial currents, SSBroken dynamically by gluons interactions, but still conserved, of course). It all works with the secondary magic of the EW sector of the SM, which gives fermions a mass while preserving chiral symmetries.